# Monodevelop run button grayed out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monodevelop

Well, the title says everything. I've just installed MonoDevelop 2.2 from my Ubuntu's package manager, then created the most basic C# 'hello world' console application. The 'run->run' menu entry is grayed out and pressing F5 doesn't work even if I can compile (for windows) it successfully.
I tried googling but found anything.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the top bar there is Active Layout button that says Default.
Open it and choose Visual Design.
Then it will work